# Node JS как достать функцию из другого файла js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пишу код на Node JS и столкнулся с проблемой.

Мне нужно достать функцию из другого JS файла. Я делал с помощью `require`, но не получилось.

Вот код:

*filename.js*

```
module.exports = function Hello () {
   console.info('Привет, итс ми');
}
```

И в *importer.js*

```
const filename = require('./app.js')
else if (message == "/hello") {
    filename.Hello();
    client.chatMessage(steamID, "Дал ответ!");
    console.log("Отправил hello");
}
```

Я не так контачу? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Вы её экспортировали?

Comment: Всмысле? module.Export?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

исправте код модуля

```
module.exports.Hello = function Hello (){}
```

В подключаемом файле должно быть указано, что экспортируется. Для этого в конце файла делается запись: `module.exports.name = nameObjectExports` Пример: код модуля с названием `abracadabra.js`

```
    function moduleTest(arg){
    console.log(arg);
}

function moduleTest_2(arg){
    console.log(arg);
}

module.exports.moduleTest = moduleTest;
// после `module.exports` можно указать другое имя, по которому будет 
//вызываться желаемая функция
module.exports.qwerty = moduleTest_2;
```

Код основного файла:

```
var randomName = require("./abracadabra.js");

randomName.moduleTest("test");
randomName.qwerty("test_2");
```

Также проверьте правильность пути, к подключаемому модулю

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @snegan как это может работать, когда это named export, а у тебя используется default import?

Comment: Я не знаю. Но всё работает

Comment: Я взял твой ответ. И в module.exports дописал - .Hello. И всё

Comment: @Snegan, это не я тебе писал) Я знаю, что все работает. У тебя, правда, еще имя подключаемого файла указано неправильно. Но ты наверное уже исправил

Comment: Я @Herrgott писал. Модули исправил.

Comment: А зачем вы удалили ответ с объяснениями? Вашему текущему ответу объяснения очень не помешали бы, не должен ответ состоять из одного кода...

Comment: @ Pavel Mayorov, потому что, когда я писал ответ с объяснениями, в вопросе не было примера кода. А потом его еще и заминусовали(... Исправил